# Total execution time on Client Statistics for SQL Server Management

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm working on optimizing a fairly complex stored procedure. I'm just wondering if what I'm doing to track the improvements is a good of doing it.

I set the DBCC FREEPROCCACHE and I have Include Client Statistics in SQL Management Studio.

I look at Total execution time on the Client Statistics tab to determine if my changes are making my stored procedure faster.

Is this a good of way of measuring improvements in stored procedure? Or should I be looking at other areas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way to see how long it took to execute the query:
 . So this one took 3 seconds. 
[image]

If you want to see the performance of a query, turn on client statistics and execution plan to see the performance of each query. To turn on Client Statistics:

[image]

Result:

[image]

To turn on Execution Plan:

[image]

Result:

[image]

You can also try using 
SET STATISTICS TIME ON 
SET STATISTICS IO ON. 
They will show you the time and I/O required by each and every statement. Don't forget to turn them off when you're done. (SET STATISTICS TIME OFF , SET STATISTICS IO OFF)

Make sure every time you test a new query you clear the query cache so that the old query doesn’t affect your new test. To clear the query cache, execute this code:

```
CHECKPOINT;
GO
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS;   --Clears query cache
GO  
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE;   --Clears execution plan cache
GO
```